# How to validate user input for whether it's an integer?

Tags: c#, validation, input, console

It tells me that it can't convert int to bool.
Tried TryParse but for some reason the argument list is invalid.

Code:

```
private void SetNumber(string n)
{
    // if user input is a number then
    if (int.Parse(n)) 
    {
        // if user input is negative
        if (h < 0)
        {
            // assign absolute version of user input
            number = Math.Abs(n); 
        }
        else 
        {
            // else assign user input
            number = n;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        number = 0; // if user input is not an int then set number to 0  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `number` a bool or something? Where are you getting an error about not being able to convert int to bool?

Comment: Why the vb-style comments in C# code? Are you a VB coder coming into C#? Or a newbie putting together samples from different languages?

Answer (score 18):

You were probably very close using `TryParse`, but I'm guessing you forgot the `out` keyword on the parameter:

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(n, out value))
{

}
```

Comment: Indeed; int.Parse() returns an int, which is why you can't check it for true or false without evaluating the returned value in some way.

Answer (score 7):

Just use this:

```
int i;
bool success = int.TryParse(n, out i);
```

if the parse was successful, `success` is `true`.

If that case `i` contain the number.

You probably got the `out` argument *modifier* wrong before. It has the `out` modifier to indicate that it is a value that gets initialized within the method called.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with some simple regular expression :

```
  bool IsNumber(string text)
    {
      Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$");
      return regex.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void SetNumber(string n)
    {
        int nVal = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(n, out nVal))
        {
            if (nVal < 0)
                number = Math.Abs(nVal);
            else
                number = nVal;
        }
        else
            number = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with this code:

- Using VB-style line comments (') instead of C# slashes
- Parse for integer returns an int and not a bool
- You should use TryParse with an out value
- h does not seem to be valid at all. Is it a type for n?
- There are variables that do not seem to be defined in function scope (number) are they defined at class scope?

But try this:

```
private void SetNumber(string n)
{
    int myInt;
    if (int.TryParse(n, out myInt)) //if user input is a number then
    {
        if (myInt < 0) //if user input is negative
            number = Math.Abs(n); //assign absolute version of user input
        else //else assign user input
            number = n;
    }
    else number = 0; //if user input is not an int then set number to 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below using `int.TryParse`..

```
        private void SetNumber(string n)
        {
            int parsed = -1;
            if (int.TryParse(n, out parsed)) //if user input is a number then
            ...
```

The reason there are complaints that it cannot convert an `int` to a `bool` is because the return type of `int.Parse()` is an `int` and not a `bool` and in c# conditionals need to evaluate `bool` values.

Answer (score 1):

int.Parse will give you back an integer rather than a boolean.

You could use int.TryParse as you suggested.

```
int parsedValue;
if(int.TryParse(n, out parsedValue))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing the inner if statement has an 'h' instead of an 'n' if(h < 0).  But TryParse should work there assuming that 'number' is a class variable.

```
 private void SetNumber(string n)
    {
        int temp;
        bool success = Int32.TryParse(n, out temp);

        // If conversion successful
        if (success)
        {
            // If user input is negative
            if (temp < 0)
                number = Math.Abs(temp); // Assign absolute version of user input
            else // Assign user input
                number = temp;

        }
        else
        {
            number = 0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse will convert a string to an integer. Current you have it within an if statement, so its treating the returned value of int.Parse as a bool, which its not.

Something like this will work:

```
private void SetNumber(string n)
{
    int num = 0;
    try{
        num = int.Parse(n);
        number = Math.Abs(num);
    }catch(Exception e){
        number = 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: forgot about TryParse, haven't used C# recently see @Paul Sasik for the proper example.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the simplest way I knew how.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a, b;
        int f1, f2, x, y;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter two inputs");
        a = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        b = Console.ReadLine();
        f1 = find(a);   
        f2 = find(b);   

        if (f1 == 0 && f2 == 0)
        {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(a);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Two inputs r number \n so tha additon of these text box is= " + (x + y).ToString());
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("One or tho inputs r string \n so tha concadination of these text box is = " + (a + b));
        Console.ReadKey();
    
    }
        static int find(string s)
        {
        string s1 = "";
        int f;
         for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                string c = j.ToString();
                if (c[0] == s[i])
                {
                    s1 += c[0];
                }
            }
        
        if (s==s1)
            f= 0;
        else
            f= 1;

        return f;
    }
```

Comment: please take a minute to explain the changes/improvements you have made, so the author or other people have a chance to learn from it. unrelated: welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: "Simple way" is more complex than pretty much every other answer here.